# Get the name attributes of scandir's DirEntry object generator without a loop

Tags: python, optimization, scandir, listdir

I read that scandir is an improved version of listdir, and wanted to use it to pass along a listing of possibly large directory contents in the most efficient way.

Unlike listdir, that gives the names of the files and folders directly, scandir outputs a DirEntry object generator -

```
from scandir import scandir
from os import listdir

path='C:/'

listdir(path)                    # outputs ['$Recycle.Bin',  .. , 'Windows']
list(scandir(path))              # outputs [<DirEntry '$Recycle.Bin'>,..   ]
```

To get just the names with scandir, I currently use:

```
list(names.name for names in scandir(path))   #outputs ['$Recycle.Bin', .. ]
```

and to unpack the names in a suitable function, which is what I want, I pass along

`*(names.name for names in scandir(path))`

as the respective function argument, whereas with listdir I can just pass

`*listdir(path)`

as the argument.

Is that usage of scandir efficient? Can I perhaps somehow extract the names directly, without iterating with a for loop?

Comment: are you trying to make a "search" program that is faster than the "find" option in windows? `scandir` is almost certainly less efficient than `listdir` since it is constructing classes for each element (although it may be trivially slower)

Comment: Just pass the iterator directly and deal with it in your function? If you are going to be putting everything in a list, it sort of defeats the point.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga im pretty sure thats saying os.walk is much slower than scandir(2x?) ... im 99% sure timeit will confirm my hunch about speed ... without actually caring enough to run the test myself

Comment: @JoranBeasley Yes just confirmed with `timeit` and a relatively large directory (90k files).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Could you share the test resuts? I don't have folders  that size to test on.

Comment: @JoranBeasley I don't want to necessarily search the contents, I just thought scandir should work better based on what I read and on folders the size juanpa.arrivillaga ran the test on